# How to override cherry-pick conflicts

Tags: git, cherry-pick

Is there any method by which we can override the cherry-pick conflicts? My scenario is: If user provides three changeids, and one file is common in all the three changeids. It will result in cherry-pick conflicts. So over-riding means, the script should take that file from the third changeid.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script/ hook that do it, but keep in mind that in git many commands can get multiple commit ids as valid input.

What if the given parameter is a branch name? you will have to parse it to get the latest commit id if its not the current HEAD

I recommending of writing a script that will do what you asking it to do.

Comment: Is there any way to find the file which cause the merge conflict. I have seen the error info during merge conflict. It hardly says anything. And how can i override in script, can you explain in detail.

Comment: Try this: `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U` (U is for unmerged files = conflicts in your case)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me in finding the files causing merge conflict. In script i will add these files and do a commit and proceed further. Is it the right way to override with the latest changes?.

Comment: Hi again. if it helped you you can accept the answer. ill appreciate it. regarding your second part you sounds like it a good solution since its suites your needs.